# Convert JSON to INTeger for MongoDB?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, node.js, mongodb

*With .post of FORM data to express/node.js*

All of the values are currently stored and returned as STRings

**Am looking to have one of the data values (req.body.quantity) stored as an `INT`**

```
//POST
app.post('/add', function (req, res) {    

db.collection('demo').insert(

    {
        "title" : req.body.title,
        "quantity" : req.body.quantity,
    },

        function (err, doc) {

            getAll(res);

        });
});
```

The getAll currently looks like this:

```
//EXPRESS NODE.JS
function getAll(res) {

    db.collection('demo').find().sort( { quantity: 1 } ).toArray(function (err, docs) {

     // each doc should look like: { title: 'string', quantity: int}

        res.json({docs: docs});

    });
}
```

And the working .get:

```
// AJAX    
$('#getBtn').click(function() {
  $.get('http://localhost:9999').
   done(gotAllSuccess).
   fail(gotAllFailure);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code I believe this will fix it for you.

```
"quantity" : parseInt(req.body.quantity)
```

---

However, I recommend that you look into something like [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) if you haven't already. It's an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) for MongoDB and it lets you define *schemas* that describe how your models should look. In your case you'd be able to design a schema that looked like this:

```
// Define your schema somewhere where your app is first initialized.
// You'll also want to open your db connection here somewhere as well, but I'll
// let you figure that out. http://mongoosejs.com
var demoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ title: String, quantity: Number });
var Demo = mongoose.model('Demo', demoSchema);
// You can just pass in an object literal to mongoose.model instead of
// instantiating a Schema object, but instantiating a Schema object is what
// you'd have to do if you wanted to also add virtual methods/properties.
```

You can also add [virtual properties](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-virtual) and [virtual methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-method) to your schema here. These properties and methods don't get stored in the database.

Then you can do this:

```
// Retrieve the model you created.
var Demo = require('mongoose').model('Demo');

// Request handler for POST requests to /add
app.post('/add', function (req, res) { 
    // Create a new instance of your Demo model and populate it with data.
    var newDemo = new Demo({
        title: req.body.title,
        quantity: req.body.quantity
        // quantity will be converted to a Number because the schema defines it
        // as one.
    });
    // Mongoose documents have persistence methods on them, including save
    // which will update or insert the document depending on whether or not
    // it has an _id already.
    newDemo.save(function (err, newDemo) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        // Models also act as the API for querying. Here we find all documents,
        // sort them by quantity ascending, then execute the query.
        // Note: mongoose's query builder syntax below uses promises to make
        // queries very readable :)
        Demo.find().sort('quantity').exec(function (err, demos) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);

            // demos is an array of Demo instances, each with the same
            // persistence methods you saw above.

            // Each demo doc's properties will adhere to the defined type
            // in the schema.
            //
            // { title: 'hello', quantity: 123}

            res.json({ docs: demos });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Very cool intro to Mongoose.. Have been wondering how to dive in, and this really helps!

Comment: @StackThis if you like mongoose you might also like the wrapper I wrote for it called [mongoose-simpledb](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-simpledb). Simpledb makes it extremely easy to setup and use mongoose quickly :)

Comment: So basically, when the newDemo saves (a mongoose 'shortcut' for insert in mongodb), an anonymous function (great for the node event loop) finds all the saved newDemo (now docs in the db) sorts them by quantity, and then a subsequent anonFunction renders all the demo docs into json to then .get.. Is that correct?

Comment: Really neat.. Will definitely take a good look into -simpledb

Comment: Also check out my edit. I updated the code sample with helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use the [`Number(...)` constructor or function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

```
Number("123"); // => 123

db.collection('demo').insert(
  {
    "title" : req.body.title,
    "quantity" : Number(req.body.quantity),
  },
  // ...
```